# Parse CSV file with long strings to find specific string/value for each row

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, parsing

I trying to parse a CSV-file that contains a long string for each row.
The long string is a series of 3s and 0s (303030303030303030...)
Somewhere in the the string there is a specific of 4 digits. 
The 4 digits is a counter from 0 to 100 in hexadecimal and they are in order so the four 0s (0000) is followed by three 0s and one 1 (0001) and so on (0002.., 0003.., 0004...). 
So for each row of 3s and 0s (303030330) there will be a 4 digit number between 0000-0063 (hexs 0-100).

I wanna sort each string with the 4 digit number as the "index" for each string and save it to a new csv file.

I need to be using python3.

The CSV file looks like:
e.g

```
Number | Time | data
324      13s    0303030303(0000)30303030303...
326      13.5s  03030303(0001)3030303030303...
340      14s    3030303(0002)30303030303030...
345      14.1s  (0003)303030303030303030303...
346      14.8s  (0004)303030303030300303030...
350      15s    (0005)303030303030303030303...
...      ...    ...
450      30s    (0062)303030303030303030303...
451      31s    (0063)303030303030303030303...
```

The () is just for clear text not actually within the long string

Comment: [Sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) takes a key argument which is a callable whose argument is a sequence item and its return value is the *thing* you want to sort on. Write a function to find, extract, and return your *key* and use it for sorting.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: If its already in order, you might want to think about just recreating the column, instead of parsing and manipulating it. It would be pretty easy and only take a few lines of code.

Comment: how do i do the recreating? Are there any sorting function to call in python? Sorry im just starting to learn